# Adjective describing an avid Stack Exchange user

Tags: single-word-requests

I am looking for a single word that could describe a Stack Exchange users who contributes larger number of posts (questions or answers).

I thought about using "prominent", but I wonder if there is something more specific.

Comment: There's a few senses you might be getting at - "active" and "reputable" come to mind.

Comment: How about "crazed"?

Comment: @HotLicks "Masochist" seems a better fit....

Comment: Please read the FAQ. Good Luck.

Comment: "productive", "contributing" — or "verbose" (and I'm sure you can find dozens of synonyms for that).

Comment: I've heard the term ["power user"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=%22power%20user%22) for someone with a high rep and who is very productive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

People who post a lot are **prolific**:

> (of an artist, author, or composer) producing many works.
>   <sub>[Oxford Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/prolific)</sub>

It's usually positive, but it doesn't have to be.

Examples in use:

- [Most Prolific Answerers (with score)](https://data.stackexchange.com/pm/revision/33132/33132/most-prolific-answerers-with-score)
- [Who are the most prolific answerers for a tag?](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/139151/who-are-the-most-prolific-answerers-for-a-tag)
- [What is most constructive action to prolific, enthusiastic misinformed user's many wrong answers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/213131/323179)